# Invoke custom javascript function in flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter

1.Placed a js file in assets folder.
2.Added the path in pub spec.yaml
3.How do I invoke a function from a js file from flutter ?

I have tried the following approaches
1.String jsCode = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/temp.js');
but I am unable to invoke function of js file as it is a string.
2. imported flutter_js package but builds fails with compilation errors.

Path of js file is: assets/temp.js

**Content of temp.js**

```
function add(){
print("add");
}
```

**snippet of pubspec.yaml**
flutter:
assets:
- assets/

Please help me out here, thank you.

Comment: Don't put the JS in assets; put it in /web and include it as shown here: https://fireship.io/snippets/using-js-with-flutter-web/ Look at the chartjs package for good practice calling JS https://github.com/google/chartjs.dart/ And, finally, consider encapsulating this in a plugin.

Comment: @RichardHeap : Thank you, it does work when I run the app on chrome, but I need a solution for mobile.

Comment: You'll need to port the Javascript functions to Dart